# I keep on getting Cannot find Symbol Error when using Comparable

Tags: java, tree, heap, comparable

I keep on getting an error saying Cannot find symbol when trying to compile. The files are both in the same folder, i'm not really sure where i went wrong here.
In this assignment im supposed to write a program that reads a list of employees from a file. The name of the file will be ‘Employee.txt’. The program should output the *sorted* array to a file called “SortedEmployee.txt”. I already have the Heap class done. Need assistance please.

```
public class Employee
{
   String id;
   String name;
   String department;
   String position;
   double salary;
   int yos; //Year of Service
   
   //constructor w/ no args
   public Employee()
   {  salary = 0.0;
      id = name = department = position = "";
      yos = 0;
   
   }
   
   //constructor w/ args
   public Employee(String i, String n, String d, String p, double s, int y)
   {
      id = i;
      name = n;
      department = d;
      position = p;
      salary = s;
      yos = y;
   }
   
   public void setID(String i)
   {  id = i;}
   public void setName(String n)
   {  name = n;}
   public void setDepartment(String d)
   {department = d;}
   public void setPosition(String p)
   {position = p;}
   public void setSalary(double s)
   {salary =s;}
   public void setYOS(int y)
   {yos = y;}
   
   public String getID()
   {  return id;}
   public String getName()
   {  return name;}
   public String getDepartment()
   {return department;}
   public String getPosition()
   {return position;}
   public double getSalary()
   {return salary;}
   public int getYOS()
   {return yos;}
   
   
    public String toString()
   {
      String str =  "Emplyee Id: " + id + "\nName: " + name + 
                     "\nDepartment:  " + department + "\nPosition: " + position
                     + "\nSalary: " + salary;
                     
                            
        return str;
    }
     public int compareTo(Employee emp)
{
  int idONE = id.compareToIgnoreCase(emp.id);
  if (idONE != 0)
     return idONE;
  return 0;
}                  
   

}


public class EmployeeCOMP implements Comparable<Employee>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee emp){
       return this.id.compareToIgnoreCase(emp.id);
    }
}
```

This is the error I keep on getting.

```
EmployeeCOMP.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
       return this.id.compareToIgnoreCase(emp.id);
                  ^
  symbol: variable id
1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the instance of `EmployeeCOMP` which does not have an `id`.  In this context the `compareTo` method should be part of the `Employee` class (not a separate class):

```
public class Employee {
  ...

    public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
        return this.id.compareToIgnoreCase(emp.id);  // **this** refers to an Employee instance
    }   
}
```

Attempting to use through a separate class suggests you might be needing to implement a `Comparator`.

Comment: At the end of my Employee class I have a public int compareto already, should i keep that and completely erase the EmployeeCOMP class?

Comment: doing this gives me errors because i already have a compareto(Employee) method in my Employee class